# Text field with drop down list

Tags: vaadin, textfield

I am new at vaadin framework. I want to know how can , make make UI witch use textfield like this picture ?

[image]

please guide me. Thanks....

Comment: Show up what efforts were already done and where is the exact issue. No one will land here and do your homeworks for you.

Comment: Do you want the dropdown to give suggestions based on what a user has previously entered, or do you want a dropdown with predefined choices?

Comment: It is hard to even guess, what this field is supposed to do.  This could even be the auto-form-input from the browser.  Please add your current code or some more detailed description, what this field is supposed to do (what and when does is suggest what)

Comment: Endling thanks for your answer...I want the dropdown to give suggestions based on what a user has previously entered.How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

- If you wanted to browser localy store user inputs, the anwser is: No, because browser implementation for parsing data from
  input field have to have certian DOM strcuture. Something like: `<input>` field inside a `<form>` tag and `<submit>` button, Vaadin is component based framework and does not offer that. I belive going native HTML inside some Vaadin container should work.
- If you wanted to store data on session, I can give you some directions of implementation.